# Google cloud kubernetes switching off a node

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently testing out google cloud for a home project. I only require the node to run between a certain time slot. When I switch the node off it automatically switches itself on again. Not sure if I am missing something as I did not enabling autoscaling and it's also a General Purpose e2-small instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I switch the node off it automatically switches itself on again.
> Not sure if I am missing something as I did not enabling autoscaling
> and it's also a General Purpose e2-small instances

Kubernetes nodes are managed by the Node pool. Which you might created during your cluster creation of GKE if you are using it.

Node pool manages the number of the available node **counts**. there could be chances new nodes is getting created again or existing node starting back.

If you are on GKE and want to scale down to zero you can reduce number of node count in **Node pool** from GKE console.

Check your node pool : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#console_1

Resize your node pool from here : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#resizing_a_node_pool